# Regex only number and comma

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will accept only digits from 1-45 and comma.
No letters, no characters like this

```
1
1,2
1,17,30
1,4,5,6,7,11,22,33,44...
```

there must be no limit of length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:(?:([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])(?:,(?!$))?)+)$
```

`^`: Start of the line
`(?: ... )+`: Non-capturing group that can appear one or more times
`(?:([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])(?:,(?!$))?)+`: Non-capturing group containing the following elements:
`([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])`: A capturing group matching numbers from 1 to 45
`[1-9]`: Single digit numbers from 1 to 9
`[1-3][0-9]`: Two-digit numbers from 10 to 39
`4[0-5]`: Two-digit numbers from 40 to 45
`(?:,(?!$))?`: An optional non-capturing group that matches a comma
`,`: The comma character
`(?!$)`: A negative lookahead to make sure the comma isn't followed by the end of the line
`$`: End of the line

This will reject any entrance with a number greater than 45

^(?:(?:([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))(?:,|$))+$

1. `^`: Start of the line
2. `(?: ... )+`: Non-capturing group that can appear one or more times

   - `(?:([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))`: Non-capturing group containing the following elements:

     1. `([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5])`: A capturing group matching numbers from 1 to 45

        - `[1-9]`: Single digit numbers from 1 to 9
        - `[1-3][0-9]`: Two-digit numbers from 10 to 39
        - `4[0-5]`: Two-digit numbers from 40 to 45
   - `(?:,|$)`: Non-capturing group that matches a comma or the end of the line

     1. `,`: The comma character
     2. `$`: End of the line
3. `$`: End of the line

### Test

https://regex101.com/r/6f3Ita/1

Also, the first one missed input not ending by comma:
^(?:(?:([1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-5]))(?:,(?=\d)|$))+$

Comment: i dont want to allow like this "1,2,48" becuase 48 is more than 45 but the regex allow this

Comment: @chea And you did test that the regex given in this answer does accept 48?

Comment: match 5 seems to be a match, see: https://regex101.com/r/6f3Ita/1,  or just a plain test to match `48`, https://regex101.com/r/PRxVAe/1